# Rewrapping PPPoE to PPTP

Tags: vpn, pptp, pppoe

It is my understanding that PPPoE is just PPP wrapped in Ethernet packets.  PPTP is PPP tunneled over GRE/IP.  So, my question is, is it possible to take incoming PPPoE packets and easily rewrap the PPP inside as PPTP?  What I want is for a PPPoE-aware device (such as most home routers) to be able to speak PPTP transparently through another device which "translates".

Answer (score 2):

I've not seen conversion done between PPPoE and PPTP, but things along that line are doable -- I've seen a setup where we had an L2TP tunnel to another ISP, where they proxied the PPP(oATM, I think?) from their customers over the L2TP tunnel, which terminated the PPP session on our RAS.